# Reuse environments in config.groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy

is it somehow possible in `groovy.config` file to override existing environments or reuse them witout writing your own `ConfigSlurper`  ?

What I mean is that I have 4-5 different environments with tons of config and only some small parts differ in them smth like :

```
environments { 
    dev {... a lot of same configs
      server = localhost:8800
      db = localhost:4444
    }
}
```

And I would like to have next environment called for example `pre-prod` that
has most of the config same as dev apart from those `server` and `db`.
Is it doable in `gradle.build` or in `groovy` somehow ?

Comment: You could write a method that applies the configs, then pass parameters to override the differences?

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was wondering whether something like 
```pre-prod = override(dev)``` is possible directly in config groovy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
  if (grails.util.Environment.current.name == "development") {...}
```

And you can write your conditions taking into account your needs. Example:

```
  if (grails.util.Environment.current.name == "development" || Grails.utils.environment.current.name=="test") {...}
```